# Visualizing intervals with range bar charts in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart

Is it possible to have a horizontal range bar using Chartjs?

For example I have this data point

```
{x: 1 , y: [40, 60]}
```

In horizontal bars the axis are swapped.
Using horizontal bar means the range bar is on the X axis with a range between 40-60 on the Y axis with point 1.

Answer (score 2):

As it seems, people at chart.js are aware that this is an interesting feature: [chart.js issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4863)